Filter and condense a polars dataframe into a few columns of lists
Due to some circumstances I can only work with polars 0.18.4
Given a list of column names in the variable column_names(more than 20, but in this example reduced to 3) and the dataframe below:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "column1": [2, 1, 3],
    "column2": [0, 2, 0],
    "column3": [0, 0, 4]
})

Output:
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ column1 ┆ column2 ┆ column3 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2       ┆ 0       ┆ 0       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 0       │
│ 3       ┆ 0       ┆ 4       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

The original dataframe is sparse and I would like to condense it into the following format with the following tranformations:

Condense the values into a column of lists named column_values. The corresponding column name will appear in another column named column_names
All values below a certain threshold will not appear in column values. In the below example, only values more than 1 are included (the second row is missing the intended 1)
Column values should be arranged in descending order, with the corresponding column name also arranged in the same order
Please try to minimize memory usage!

The output should look like this:
┌────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ column_names           ┆ column_values │
│ ---                    ┆ ---           │
│ list[str]              ┆ list[i64]     │
╞════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ ["column1"]            ┆ [2]           │
│ ["column2"]            ┆ [2]           │
│ ["column3", "column1"] ┆ [4, 3]        │
└────────────────────────┴───────────────┘



unpivot() to convert columns to rows.
filter() to remove rows which do not fall under condition.
group_by() and agg() to aggregate results into lists.

(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    # or .with_columns(index = pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    .unpivot(index="index",variable_name="column_names", value_name="column_value")
    .filter(pl.col.column_value > 1)
    .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.all().sort_by("column_value", descending=True))
    .drop("index")
)

┌────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ column_names           ┆ column_value │
│ ---                    ┆ ---          │
│ list[str]              ┆ list[i64]    │
╞════════════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ ["column1"]            ┆ [2]          │
│ ["column3", "column1"] ┆ [4, 3]       │
│ ["column2"]            ┆ [2]          │
└────────────────────────┴──────────────┘

Alternatively, you could probably do it without unpivoting. This could work more memory efficient (although I didn't really test it).

.struct() to combine column name and column value into one object.
.concat_list() to create lists instead of columns.
when/then to set values which don't fall under condition to null.
list.drop_nulls() remove nulls from the lists.
list.sort() sorting lists.
list.eval() separating values into 2 different columns.

(
    df
    .select(
        data = pl.concat_list(
            pl.when(pl.col(c) > 1)
            .then(pl.struct(value=pl.col(c), name=pl.lit(c)))
            for c in df.schema.keys()
        )
        .list.drop_nulls()
        .list.sort(descending=True)
    )
    .select(
        column_names = pl.col.data.list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("name")),
        column_values = pl.col.data.list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("value"))
    )
)

┌────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ column_names           ┆ column_values │
│ ---                    ┆ ---           │
│ list[str]              ┆ list[i64]     │
╞════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ ["column1"]            ┆ [2]           │
│ ["column2"]            ┆ [2]           │
│ ["column3", "column1"] ┆ [4, 3]        │
└────────────────────────┴───────────────┘

or, if list.drop_nulls() is not available in your version of polars:
(
    df
    .select(
        data = pl.concat_list(
            pl.when(pl.col(c) > 1)
            .then(pl.concat_list(pl.struct(value=pl.col(c), name=pl.lit(c))))
            .otherwise([])
            for c in df.schema.keys()
        )
        .list.sort(descending=True)
    )
    .select(
        column_names = pl.col.data.list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("name")),
        column_values = pl.col.data.list.eval(pl.element().struct.field("value"))
    )
)


Hi Roman, thanks for the answers! unfortunately I forgot to add in that I can only work with polars 0.18.4 for now and for the first answer that version doesn't yet have with_row_index, and for the second the version is lacking drop nulls. Could you suggest alternatives to these? Thanks!

you could replace with_row_index() with .with_columns(index = pl.int_range(pl.len()))

Yes, shortly after I typed that I substituted it with arange, but it turns out that 0.18.4 doesn't have unpivot as well

try melt().

As expected, melting to create the extra rows made it too large to process. I think I should be able to do it in batches

check another possible variant of working with lists. I think 'list' approach should be easier to stream but I'm still not sure about performance
